# Regex result in one expresion

Tags: c++, regex

i have an example string like the one below

```
http://rp-F083B8.local/?mac=00:26:32:F0:83:B8&nav=4702&hw=STEM_125-14_v1.0
```

from this text i need to extract the mac address from the middle, but without the semicolon in-between.

i have managed to do this in 2 expresion like this:
`(\w{2})[:](\w{2})[:](\w{2})[:](\w{2})[:](\w{2})[:](\w{2})` ==> `00:26:32:F0:83:B8`

and another `/\W/` applied to the previous result ==> `002632F083B8`

but the requirement is to do this in just one expression.
is there another way to do this in just expression? 
thanks,

Comment: Do it with regex `replace` method. See https://regex101.com/r/w0IamZ/1. Note you can't match disjoint pieces of text within 1 match operation. Thus, you need to replace/match multiple occurrences + join.

Comment: Please let know your programming environment

Comment: my programming language is C# and C++. i will try this way, if just one expression cannot be achieved. thank you

Comment: No, there should be one per question, else, it is  too broad. These two are quite different, please choose one, and update the question with the code that fails.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this satisfies your requirement of single expression

```
#include<regex>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

std::string foo(std::string s)
{
    // match the mac address, but don't capture colons
    static const std::regex r {R"~~(^.*mac=(\w{2}):(\w{2}):(\w{2}):(\w{2}):(\w{2}):(\w{2}).*$)~~"};
    // join the 6 bits together
    return std::regex_replace(s, r, "$1$2$3$4$5$6"); 
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "http://rp-F083B8.local/?mac=00:26:32:F0:83:B8&nav=4702&hw=STEM_125-14_v1.0";
    std::cout << foo(s);
}
```

This is 2 regexes but easier to understand

```
std::string foo(std::string s)
{
    static const std::regex mac_address {R"~~(^.*mac=((\w{2}:?)6}).*$)~~"};
    static const std::regex without_colons {R"~~((\w{2}):?)~~"}; 
    return std::regex_replace(
             std::regex_replace(s, mac_address, "$1"),
                 without_colons, "$1");
}
```